# In django admin, is it possible to dynamically filter available choices based on on previous field selection

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django dynamic forms - on-the-fly field population?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998428/django-dynamic-forms-on-the-fly-field-population)

My first model is called Company. When a company is created via admin one of the fields is a horizontal_filter that allows me to add users to that company.

My second model is called Team. When I create a new team the first field in my admin form is company and then I have a horizontal_filter that allows me to select users.

Is there any way for me to only show users that are a member of the chosen company in this horizontal_filter field?

for clarity here are my models and admin forms:

Company model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.company_nam
```

Company admin form:

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("users",)

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Team model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    team_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.team_title
```

Team Admin form:

```
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("users",)

admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

Comment: You can use smart select app https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/

Comment: Unfortunately smart selects has no functionality for managing manytomany relationships, only foreignkey.