# Creating Dynamic dropdown in django modelform

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a single class with three fields in in my model. I want to make a dynamic dropdown so that when I select first field the second has to change and so on. I have gone through this question [Django/jQuery Cascading Select Boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes)
but it seems like the solution there assumes multiple classes but I have a single class.

PS: I am a novice in Jquery and Javascript so anything which mainly involves django manipulation would be of great help.

Comment: Well, if you want to do it in a single page(without reloading), using Javascript is your only option, else you can implement it using django.

Comment: I don't need it in a single page. In fact I want to render it to another page.

Comment: By without reloading did you mean selecting options?? If yes yeah I must use js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great library for django called django-autocomplete-light

You can look at http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html