# Django - Populating Drop One Select From Another

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have an implementaton of the above in my own environment (with various parts of it documented around so!) but simply cannot get it to work properly. I'm at the stage where the web pape renders only as a submit button with no select boxes.

I need a model form which has a select box which I populate with a list of choices and then another select box which populates via jquery based on the selected item of the select box. A view which render_to_responses to a template this and uses the http post/get methods to use the jquery function to fill the second select box then save these two values into the two fields of the model as defined in the model form.

I realize this is specific (but I'm not trying to get somebody to do my work for me!) for me it'd be so useful to see another method of implementation as I'm just going in cirlces.

If you have some time then I'd really appreciate a run-through of your method - preferably with some source code. If you want to see any of my code then please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django/jQuery Cascading Select Boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes)

Comment: no i don't think so, there is no reference to a model or form on this example - although the template and view are useful

Answer (score 2):

You can simply doing something like this :

**template.html**

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This part is filled during the loading of the page. (by Django)

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    sort1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('0', 'All'), ('1', '...'), ...), initial='0', required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'sort-select', 'id': 'sort1'}))
    sort2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('0', ''), ), required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'sort-select', 'id': 'sort2'}))
```

Here is the form for which you specified the content for the first list and a second list with only one default item.

**main.css**

```
.sort-select#sort2 { display: none; }
```

**views.py**

```
from simplejson import dumps, loads

def sort1_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, {'form': form}, 'template.html')

def sort2_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        # Add more check over this data
        req = loads(request.body)
        data = dumps(modellist2.objects.filter(parent_list=req['parent_list']))
        return HttpResponse(data)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(dumps({'error': 'HTTP Method error'}))
```

In this file we write two view functions : the first to load the template once and the second for the Ajax call.

**main.js**

```
(function() {
    $(".sort-name#sort1").change(function() {
        var sort1_id = $(this).find(':selected').val();

        // Empty the second <select>
        $('.sort-select#sort2').empty();

        // Ajax call - HTTP GET Method
        $.get('/list2/', {parent_list: sort1_id}, function(data) {
            // Append option tags to the select sort 2
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                $('.sort-select#sort2').append("<option value=" + data.id + ">" + data.value + "</option>");
            }
        });

        // Display sort 2
        $('.sort-select#sort2').show();
    });    
}).call(this);
```

In your main.js, we simply catch events when our first *select* tag (select#sort1) changes, get the selected item and make an Ajax call to obtain the content of the second list based on one parameter : here, the selected id of the first list. Your Python function sort2_view is called (I don't implement the urls.py but it's very easy to do) and return a JSON string which contains our second list content. It remains to append it to the second *select* tag (select.#sort2).

Comment: this looks good, thanks! before i try and implement with my project one thing - how do you reference the select container from the js? i see you've written $(".sort-name#sort1").change(function() { how did you set this?

Comment: I just fixed a little thing in my forms.py. In fact, the CSS class *sort-name* and id *sort1* are specified within the TextInput widget. In this way, my `<select>` tags can be find with jQuery. Note you can create a templatetags for this purpose too (http://vanderwijk.info/blog/adding-css-classes-formfields-in-django-templates/).

Comment: why use a text input widget?

Comment: if i have TableName = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'sort-select'}) can i reference this in the jquery event as $('.sort-select#TableName').change(function() ?

Comment: My mistake, use *Select* widget instead of *TextInput*.

Comment: but can i refer to it in the script as .sort-select#TableName'?

Comment: The CSS id come from the Select widget : `sort2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('0', ''), ), required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'sort-select', 'id': 'sort-two'}))` and use it in your js like this : `$('.sort-select#sort-two').change ...`

Comment: what if i'm not using a .css? (i'm not)

Comment: You can add a *name* attribute to your `<select>` tag and access it in your JS like this : $('select[name="sort1"]'). But it should be nice to add CSS to disabled the second `<select>` tag. In this way, your users should select within the first list and after this choice, the second list will be filled and available.

Comment: will add css to everything after it's functional! i have no select tag - i have rendered the form as ul {{ form.as_ul }} so haven't defined any in the template. can i add the attribute in the forms.py? (thanks for helping so far!)

Comment: In the *forms.py* of my example, you implement all fields which populate your form. If you render your form within your template file like this : `{{ form.as_ul }}`, Django will generate for you the `<select>` tags. I encourage you to write your own *forms.py*, render it without any js and inspect the HTML code generated by Django.