# Django - ModelChoiceField queryset based on a parent ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` form that has two `ModelChoiceField` inputs where `child` is dependent on `parent`:

```
parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    widget=forms.Select(attrs=_default_attrs),
    queryset=Parent.objects.all()
)
child = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    widget=forms.Select(attrs=_default_attrs),
    queryset=Child.objects.none()
)
```

I'm using javascript to populate child through an API. With the above code, validation fails since `queryset` is set to none - i.e. no items are valid.

Now I can set `queryset` to `Child.objects.all()` which will solve the validation issue, however it's impractical since `child` has thousands of items.

I'm aware that I can override `queryset` in `__init__()` and this is what I'm trying to do, however, unlike most cases that I searched for in stackoverflow, `child` is dependent on the value of `parent` which I'm having problems retrieving. This is what I tried:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NewPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['child'].queryset = Child.objects.filter(parent=self.fields['parent'])
```

This raises the following:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ModelChoiceField'
```

Exploring `self.fields['parent']`:

```
(Pdb) pprint(dir(self.fields['parent']))
[...
 'bound_data',
 'cache_choices',
 'choice_cache',
 'choices',
 'clean',
 'creation_counter',
 'default_error_messages',
 'default_validators',
 'empty_label',
 'empty_values',
 'error_messages',
 'help_text',
 'hidden_widget',
 'initial',
 'label',
 'label_from_instance',
 'localize',
 'prepare_value',
 'queryset',
 'required',
 'run_validators',
 'show_hidden_initial',
 'to_field_name',
 'to_python',
 'valid_value',
 'validate',
 'validators',
 'widget',
 'widget_attrs']
```

None of them was useful, `bound_data` looked like what I want but even that didn't work.

How do I approach this? What I need is to set the `queryset` of `child` to the appropriate subset based on `parent`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to change values on the fly. You cannot do it this way, because `__init__` is an initializer, and not called every time the value changes. This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes

Comment: @karthikr `self._raw_value('parent')` did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes), I ended up using `self._raw_value('parent')` which solved my problem.

**Update:** Django 1.9 removed `_raw_value()`, here is the alternative:

```
self.fields['parent'].widget.value_from_datadict(
    self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix('parent')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override 'is_valid' function of modelform.

```
def is_valid(self):

        # run the parent validation first
        valid = super(SomeForm, self).is_valid()

        if not valid:
            return valid
```

You can check this blog for details: http://chriskief.com/2012/12/16/override-django-form-is_valid/

Comment: I would probably do this in `clean` instead. Regardless, to validate `child` I would need the value of `parent`, which takes me back to the original problem - not being able to retrieve `parent`'s value.