# Dynamic dropdowns based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I have two dropdown boxes and how is it possible  select a value from the first one (*get_tests()*), the second is populated with values that depend on the first (*get_options(test)*)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def get_tests():
return ["Test1", "Test2"]

def get_options(test):
options = {"Test1": ["Test1_option_a", "Test1_option_b"],
      "Test2": ["Test2_option_a", "Test2_option_b"]}
return options[test]

@app.route('/search', methods=["GET"])
def search():
test = flask.request.args.get('tests')

return flask.render_template('search.html', tests=get_tests())

@app.route('/results', methods=["GET"])
def results():
test = flask.request.args.get('tests')
option = flask.request.args.get('options')
return flask.render_template('results.html', test=test, option=option)
```

*search.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url_for('results')}}" method="get">

      <select name="tests">
      {% for test in tests %}
        <option selected value="{{test}}">{{test}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <BR/>
      <select name="options">
      <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
      {% for option in options %}
        <option selected value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>

      <BR/>
      <input type="submit" name="go" value="SEARCH"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*results.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
{{test}}
{{option}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once you select the first one you could use $.ajax from jQuery to send the value to another endpoint for it to return a list to populate the second. This would not be done in the templates though.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not quite sure how to do it. I found few django  framework examaples ([1](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/), [2](http://dustindavis.me/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes)), but I am not quite sure how to convert it to Flask framework

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159278/no-module-named-flask-ext-wtf-selectfield) I found a solution which is very similar.