# form._raw_value(fieldname) gone in Django 1.9

Tags: django, deprecated

I have code which uses `form._raw_value(fieldname)`.

This is gone in Django 1.9.

Is there a way to access the raw value in 1.9+?

**Update**

I am only migrating the code to Django 1.9. Up to now I have no deeper understanding of what's going on there in detail.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with it? there may be better ways

Comment: Note that the leading underscore is a hint that this is a private method which you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: @DanielRoseman like `_meta` in Django models? :-) ... Yes, I know `_raw_value()` was for internal use only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/forms/forms.py#L312), the `_raw_value` method is only 3 lines long, so it would be easy to add it as a function to your code.

```
def _raw_value(form, fieldname):
    field = form.fields[fieldname]
    prefix = form.add_prefix(fieldname)
    return field.widget.value_from_datadict(form.data, form.files, prefix)
```

Then change your code from `form._raw_value(fieldname)` to `_raw_value(form, fieldname)`.