# Getting started building a template/view for a django model that joins two models together

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form where I can create and edit a group (a business really).   Though I want to be able to say this business has many locations.  I have the models written but the UI is giving me trouble.

I think mostly my question would be answered by how to update the Group model (creating/editing a group) and the GroupLocations model with a single form (adding an address as a new location if need be) so almost three models with a single form?

The models are:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=50,  null=True, blank=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=50,  null=True, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_contact= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    npi =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name = 'billing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    mailing_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', related_name = 'mailing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    change_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    change_text = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    term_comment = models.TextField(max_length = 255,  null=True, blank=True)
    group_phone=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_fax = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_term = models.ForeignKey(GroupTerm, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #quesiton is can a group be termed many times?
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    #provider_location = models.ManyToManyField('ProviderLocations', through='GroupLocations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class GroupLocations(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doing_business_as
```

I would love to (for this model and others) mimic how the admin handles users with the nice left and right multiple select boxes: (Though not sure how the add new location maybe a button to take you to another form that somehow knows its supposed to be added to the group as well?)

[image]

I realize this is a very large question I am looking for just mostly I think how to deal with several models on one form/template rails had a word for this (the name escapes me now) and not sure what the Django paradigm is.

Comment: This widget is called the [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

Comment: So it looks like that filter_horizontal is only good for the Admin model?  I cannot apply it to my model?  Or am I reading the doc wrong? I think the other thing I was looking for also was a nested formset.  (For adding an address on the fly).

Comment: The filter_horizontal as is works on the admin forms only - you read the docs right. There might be some implementation for regular forms.  For on the fly, you can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes